# How to remove characters till semicolon from a string and keep the remaining value?

Tags: javascript

I have a value like below in a variable:

```
var str = BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00
```

I want to remove characters till semicolon and keeps everything  after semicolon. So final output will be like below :

> Output : 2,100,000.00

Can someone please help?

Comment: In Java, something like the following would do it and I'm sure JavaScript could do similar... str.substring(str.indexOf(";"));

Comment: `BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00` is not a string. `"BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00"` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(";")+1, str.length)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex and capturing groups:

```js
const str = "BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00";
const regexExp = /(.*);(.+)/;

const match = str.match(regexExp);
console.log(match[2]);
```

If you don't need the left part of your string you can remove the parenthesis from the first part of the regex.

```js
const str = "BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00";
const regexExp = /.*;(.+)/;

const match = str.match(regexExp);
console.log(match[1]);
```

If you want to modify the string you can use the replace function with a regex.

```js
const str = "BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00".replace(/.*;/,"");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Keep just the method that use replace. others are not options, because just asked for removing.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is one way:

```js
const str = "BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00";
const number = str.split(';')[1];
console.log(number);
```

You can also use destructuring:

```js
const str = "BT&nbsp;2,100,000.00";
const [trash, number] = str.split(';');
console.log(number);
```